# "Orbeon form not found" Error while opening Orbeon 4.5 form

Tags: orbeon

I am working on Orbeon 4.5 forms.

While I try to open the form with a random `documentid` such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/AppName/formName/edit/randomDocumentId
```

I am getting "Orbeon form not found" error. I think it's influenced by the document_id.

If my understanding is correct, both the above link and:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/AppName/formName/edit
```

should give me the same result.

And I noticed Its working fine in 4.4 with same property file.

Below is my properties-local.xml

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.uri" value="/fr/service/mysql"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.datasource" value="orbeonDS"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="mysql"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.app1.*" value="close clear pdf email workflow-send"/>
</properties>
```

Being a newbie to Orbeon web forms so I am not sure whether I missed any configuration to get this corrected in 4.5

Any inputs to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See my reply below. What do you mean by "working fine in 4.4"? What is your expected behavior when accessing this URL with a random id or with no id at all?

Comment: Thanks for your response, In 4.4, when I am launching `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/AppName/formName/edit` or with any random id, its opening the form in edit mode , but later is not happening in 4.5 (with random id).

Comment: Also in 4.4 when I click on save button it will save the form in database with the random id provided in the url

Comment: Which form data is it editing though? If there is no existing form data, you shouldn't use `/edit` but `/new`.

Answer (score 0):

URLs that look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/AppName/formName/edit/documentId
```

are meant to load form data with id `documentId` from the database. If there is no data with that id in the database, it is the correct behavior to get a "page not found" error.

Similarly, you should never be able to access:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/AppName/formName/edit
```

without a document id. It is also correct to get a "page not found" error.

To open a form definition without existing data, use instead:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/AppName/formName/new
```